# Xcode: How to refactor/rename method and ADD (or REMOVE) its PARAMETERS?

Tags: xcode5, automated-refactoring

Is Xcode 5 able to change method's signature? As far as I can tell no, but I'd like to be shown wrong.

If I either try to add (or remove) a method's parameter, I am welcomed by the `Needs 1 fewer (more) colon to match original` error.

Must I really do a manual refactor in this case?

Comment: This is not possible with Xcode 6 also.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the first method name with the colon ("startRequest:") and then click on Refactor-> Rename

Example:

```
- (void)startRequest:(NSString *)url with:(NSDictionary *)post
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/RefactorRenaming/RefactorRenaming.html

Comment: At first, I was taken aback by your suggestion that it matters which _part_ of the method you right-click on (i.e. `startRequest:` rather than `with:`), but now I see that you probably misread my question: **can you add/remove a _parameter_?**

Comment: No I can't add/remove parameters

Answer (score 0):

As far I have also been unable to find a way to do this. In general Xcode is not very good for refactoring.

Therefore, I want to suggest you to **look for other IDEs to use for refactoring**. As a matter of fact, this is almost a common approach. I am unable to point you which IDE would be ideal for this though, but there are a few options.